# How to use ssh for gitlab scheduled jobs

Tags: ssh, gitlab

We recently changed our repo to use SSH and now our scheduled jobs wont run
This is the error we are seeing

```
Running with gitlab-runner 10.2.0 (0a75cdd1)
  on ff (4b9268cd)
Using Shell executor...
Running on pro1.staging.cardstream.net...
Cloning repository...
Cloning into '/home/gitlab-runner/builds/4b9268cd/0/Graham/QA_TEST'...
fatal: repository 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@dev.cardstream.com/Graham/QA_TEST.git/' not found
ERROR: Job failed: exit status 1
```

I would be grateful if someone could shed some light on this

Thanks

Comment: `fatal: repository 'http://...` Looks like it's still trying to use HTTP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that I have misunderstood after being misled by various internet postings.

It not possible to have gitlab use ssh when cloning a project within a job